# Copy large PostgreSQL table to multiple csv files with limited row number

Tags: postgresql, csv

Is there a way, using a sql function or an already existing psql function, to copy a very large table into multiple csv files and specify the maximum number of rows allowed in the output files ?

For example, a 35 million rows table would output 35 csv files of 1 million rows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**If the records don't have a embedded newlines** in text fields, so that there is a strict [one line = one record] mapping, you may pass the output of `\copy csv` in psql to the Unix command [split](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_(Unix)). For instance:

```
\copy (your query here) TO program 'split --lines 1000000' (format csv)
```

See the options of `split` to change the format of the names of output files or the destination directory.
It can also be used server-side with `COPY` instead of `\copy` if you're superuser.

**If the records may have embedded newlines**, it's more complicated because with the above method, a record might span two consecutive files, making each file an invalid CSV file in isolation. For instance:

```
\copy (select E'1st line\n2nd line') TO program 'split --lines 1' (format csv)
```

would produce two files

```
xaa: "1st line
```

and

```
xab: 2nd line"
```

If the goal is to concatenate the files back into a single file to process it, then it doesn't matter, but if they must be processed individually, a different method should be considered.

It's possible **in psql**, but a bit involved (as opposed to writing it in a programming language). As of PostgreSQL 12, csv is a native output format in psql so a cursor on the query might be used with `FETCH 1000000` statements doing the actual cut-and-retrieve. The skeleton for a piece of script that should work would look like this:

```
\pset format csv
\pset tuples_only on
begin;
declare c cursor for your-query-here;
fetch 1000000  from c \g file1.csv
fetch 1000000  from c \g file2.csv
... as many times as necessary...
close c;
end;
```

Because there is no looping construct in psql and assuming you don't know in advance how many fetch steps are needed, you have to generate that piece of script in a previous step that computes the `count(*)` of the resultset and emits `(count(*)+NR-1)/NR` times `fetch NR from...` commands to numbered files like above, where `NR` is your number of records per file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll try as soon as I can !